# Could not load type from assembly with optimizeCompilations="true"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I do some load optimization experiments I have  include optimizeCompilations="true"  to     `<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" optimizeCompilations="true" debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">`
but I got an error

```
Could not load type 'WebSome' from assembly 'App_LIB, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

How I can fix it ?
I added this assembly to   list but it doesn't help. 
my library is 3rd party and by some reason it is old and no namespace inside.

Comment: [That flag is designed to speed up compilation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/04/15/a-new-flag-to-optimize-asp-net-compilation-behavior.aspx) and should not affect type loading.

Comment: When you set the flag to false, does the error go away?

Comment: It is working well in false casr